# Como eu identifico qual elemento/pseudo-elemento eu tenho que pegar para atribuir alguma estilização (css)?

Tags: css

Exemplo:

Eu tenho o seguinte botão e gostaria de adicionar a propriedade `:hover`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="botaoDesloga">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger  btnSair" title="Sair" id="divBtnSair" style="background-color: #4d004d; border-color: #4d004d;"> <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>  </button>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Mas se inspeciono o elemento, o tools do browser me da as seguintes opções:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minhas dúvidas são:

Quando existir **ID** para o elemento e **classe**, eu uso qual dos dois ?

Quando o elemento esta dentro de um **DIV**, eu uso o ID da **div** ?

Como eu sei quando tenho que usar `.algumCoisa` ou `algumaCoisa#OutraCoisa`
para iniciar o **css** do cujo dito ?

Comment: Só uma dica, evite sempre usar ID para colocar estilo css no elemento, sempre de preferencia ara classe, pois com ID vc cria uma classe muito forte e depois só consegue mudar o estilo do elemento usando !important. Então evite isso `.algumaCoisa#OutraCoisa` de preferencia por isso: `.algumaCoisa.OutraCoisa` e no elemento `classe="algumaCoisa OutraCoisa"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça como achar melhor!

> Quando existir ID para o elemento e classe, eu uso qual dos dois ?

**Com o ID:**

```
#id_do_elemento {
    /* estilização */
}
```

**Com a classe:**

```
.classe_do_elemento {
    /* estilização */
}
```

> Quando o elemento esta dentro de um DIV, eu uso o ID da div ?

**Com herança (apenas filhos):**

```
<style type="text/css">
    div#id_da_div > div {
        /* estilização */
    }
</style>

<div id="id_da_div">
    <div>Esta div será estilizada</div>
    <div>
        Esta div também será estilizada
        <div>Esta div NÃO será estilizada</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Com herança (filhos, netos, ...):**

```
<style type="text/css">
    div#id_da_div div {
        /* estilização */
    }
</style>

<div id="id_da_div">
    <div>Esta div será estilizada</div>
    <div>
        Esta div também será estilizada
        <div>Esta div também será estilizada</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Leitura recomendada: [Seletores CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Getting_Started/Seletores)

Answer (score 1):

Bem o id você deve usar quando quer que somente aquele elemento tenha um estilo próprio. 
 No `html` você atribui um `id` ao elemento dessa forma `id="umId"` e no `css` para estilizar esse id você usa `#umId`.

Já com class você pode estilizar mais de um elemento, quem conter aquela class atribuída sera estilizado conforme no css.
 No `html` voce atribui uma class dessa forma `class="algumaClasse"` e no css você estiliza essa class assim: `.algumaClasse`

Se você tem um elemento dentro de uma `div` você deve usar o `id` do elemento, pois se usar o `id` da `div` ela que será estilizada.

Se caso você se deparar no seu arquivo `.css` com `algumaCoisa#OutraCoisa`, isso condiz que você tem `algumaCoisa` que pode ser uma html com um id `#OutraCoisa` exemplo: `div#algumId` isso no `html` é o mesmo que `<div id="algumId"></div>`